# Display one post based on ID from $_GET

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using products as a 'custom post type' then I'm displaying a gallery of all products on the home page with a buy button next to each one.  When the buy button is clicked, I would like it to redirect to a page with some more info of that product and a checkout form.  What do I need to send to the URL using the button to retrieve this type of page?  Should I just write my own query or is there something in wordpress that can do this for me?

This is my form right now:

```
<form class='product_form' action="checkout" method="get">
<input name="post_id" type="hidden" value="<?=$post->ID?>"/>
<input type='image' src='<?php  bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/buy.png' class='wpsc_buy_button' /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reach the "single" page of a custom post type (or even a regular post), you can do this by going to `http://example.com?p=[post_id]&post_type=[post_type_name]`. If you use *Pretty permalinks* WordPress will redirect you to the "canonical" link, which may look like `http://example.com/my-post-type/my-post-name/`.

So by changing the `target` of your form and the `post_id` hidden input to `p` it should work:

```
<form class='product_form' action="checkout" method="get" target="<?php home_url(); ?>">
<input name="p" type="hidden" value="<?=$post->ID?>"/>
<input type='image' src='<?php  bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/buy.png' class='wpsc_buy_button' /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably loop through using [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) (use a [custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)), and then use [the_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink).